# Compare stored placeholders with strings

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to obtain an ID from the DB and in my Where clause I compare a stored string with placeholders on which I want to validate against a certain value. For example:

```
ID_COLUMN     stringWithPlaceholder_COLUMN
1             Center Cost % and %           

Select ID_COLUMN 
from table_example 
where stringWithPlaceholder_COLUMN 
      like 'Center Cost 123 and 21'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: LIKE uses the pattern on the left to match against the value on the right, not the other way round. The pattern in that query contains *no* wildards so it's equivalent to `stringWithPlaceholder_COLUMN  = 'Center Cost 123 and 21'`

Comment: You're right. So i just inverted the like order statement and it's now working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the `LIKE` is inverted. The pattern to match against comes after the `LIKE` keyword. It should be:

```
WHERE
    'Center Cost 123 and 21' LIKE stringWithPlaceholder_COLUMN
```